# Heroku No such app for Dropbox based app

Tags: heroku, dns, dropbox

I had a app hosted on 'inputbox.herokuapp.com'.

My app was giving error even after successful deployment. So, I deleted the app and recreated the same app.

But now I am getting error message as:

```
"Heroku | No such app
There is no app configured at that hostname.
Perhaps the app owner has renamed it, or you mistyped the URL."
```

I looked around for heroku docs but nothing works.
I dont know how to get this fixed. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what apps you currenty have using

```
heroku apps
```

It should say something like

```
=== My Apps
inputbox
```

If it doesn't, then you know what the problem is. Let's say it has one of those silly generated names, then you can rename it using the following command:

```
heroku apps:rename inputbox
```

Happy hacking!